# Relation Between Electric Charge And Mass

Tags: special-relativity, mass, charge, classical-electrodynamics, mass-energy

Unlike mass, magnitude of charge does not depend on the velocity/acceleration, what is the reason behind that, why can't the body just lose it's self-potential energy at higher velocities?

Comment: Who told you mass depends on velocity/acceleration?

Comment: What do you mean by "self potential energy"?

Answer (score 2):

> why can't the body just lose it's self potential energy at higher velocities?

*Because* there are **absolutely** no observations of this.

The [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) encapsulates the plethora of observations on how nature behaves at the microscopic level and the charges attributed to the elementary particles, postulated in the model, are invariant under all transformations. Actually , the [invariant masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass), i.e. the four vector length of the energy momentum vector describing a particle in  special relativity, does not change either and is a signature and input in the models.

The mass you think variable and dependent on velocity is the [relativistic mass,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass)  and has fallen on disuse  because of the confusions arising. It is useful only in very specific situations, as in a massive particle approaching the speed of light ( it never can be equal as the relativistic mass becomes infinite, implying infinite energy input needed).

Comment: I'm a little confused here. I understand the disuse of the relativistic mass but isn't true that particles in large particle accelerators exhibit the effects of an increased mass at very high accelerator energies?  Is this effect just due to the difficulty of approaching c or is it a real mass increase?

Comment: A real mass increase would be an increase in the center of mass.  The relativistic increase is in the inertial mass, useful for calculating how much fuel a spaceschip should need to reach 1 percent of the velocity of light, but not for modeling interactions of elementary particles. (also for how much energy has to be supplied to the accelerator  for a particle  to reach 1 percent of the velocity of light)